# Rscript: command not found Automator

Tags: r, macos, automator, rscript

I want to automate a script in mac. I followed [this post](https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-source-an-r-script-automatically-on-a-mac-using-automator-and-ical/) but Automator throws an error `-: Rscript: command not found`. 
Actually running the simple command `Rscript` in Automator doesn't work. But it works within Terminal...
Any suggestions ?

I tried to install the most recent version of R (3.6.2) but the paradox remains.

Version info:

```
R version 3.6.2 (2019-12-12) -- "Dark and Stormy Night"
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
```

Comment: Most likely your R installation is somewhere that gets put on `PATH` in in a startup script like `.bash_profile` or `.zshrc` or similar that isn't being read, so you'll need to pass a fully-qualified path to the executable, e.g. `/usr/local/bin/R --slave -e "rnorm(1)"`. Find the correct path by running `which Rscript` in a terminal where it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by @alistaire, using `/usr/local/bin/R --slave -e` instead of `Rscript` works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding another use case, when R program is in different location, R workspace should be ignored, and input is an R file to be processed.

```
/usr/bin/R --vanilla --slave -f "src/parallel.R"
```